# IntelliJ keeps changing my modules folder settings, I want it to be Test

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have a regular maven module setup like:

```
src/main/java/...
src/main/test/com/example/...
```

So I have a junit test etc. inside my test folder, but for some reason after a while the folder setting reverts back to the default and then I can't run my tests using the right-click run test option.

I have to go back into the module settings and change it back to test.
This doesn't happen with my other maven modules (its a multi-module project).

What could the reason be?

I'm using version 12.1.4 ultimate.

Comment: What do you mean by "after a while the folder setting reverts back to the default"? Do you mean it is no longer marked green as a test source root? Any what does your pom look like - specifically is there anything in it that includes, excludes or otherwise redefines test sources?

Comment: @vikingsteve yes the color changes to the default color, and it isn't green and as a result the right-click run test option is also gone.  My pom is very simple, it only has a property and some dependancies listed.  I don't define anything else (like test sources etc) in my pom or parent pom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that this works fine for me on Intellij 12.0.4, 12.1.5 and 13.x (all Ultimate versions).

When I mark a folder (`src/main/test` in my experiment) it stays marked as a 'Test Source Root' after a restart.

(It's possibly a typo but) the directory structure you mentioned does not adhere to the maven [Standard Directory Layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html). If you move `src/main/test/java/com/example` to `src/test/java/com/example` (notice that there is a `java` in there, so `test/java/com` instead  of `test/com`) you wouldn't have to explicitly mark the test folder.